# opamp single supply output AC (audio) voltage limit

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, audio, signal

I build non-inverting op amp with single supply voltage cca 9V. The basic scheme is shown in the figure below:
[image: sigle ended opamp]

How to limit output AC signal if the base DC voltage is at half the supply voltage 4.5 V ( see the figure below).
[image]

I want output AC voltage to be max cca +- 2 V (lsl 2.5 V , usl 6.5 V "audio signal") to ensuring the stability of the next circuit. I dont want to clamp the signal i want to stop the gain at that voltage. How to do that?

Comment: Comparing the second plot with your text, please confirm that you want to clamp the signal (distorting the waveform) and not limit the amplitude, by automatically varying the gain, to preserve the signal.

Comment: Sorry for bad information. I dont want to clamp the signal i want to stop the gain at that voltage..

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and updating the question. If you search for AGC (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=automatic+gain+control) will find several suggestions to implement this.